# how to make BQ extract from table to GCS files use encoding utf-8

Tags: google-cloud-platform, utf-8, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to run a bq job that that does the export to GCS files, how can I make it to extract them with encoding `UTF-8`

the part am using to extract is:

```
new JobConfigurationExtract()
      .setSourceTable(sourceTableReference)
      .setDestinationFormat("CSV")
      .setDestinationUris(ImmutableList.of(destinationUri))
```

how can I configure this to use `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: Currently, [there is no API option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationextract) to specify an export encoding type, you can file a Feature Request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685&pli=1) if you want to. But BQ should automatically export as UTF-8.

Comment: Are you getting a different encoding when exporting to CSV? Which one and how did you verify it? If you're seeing unexpected characters then check: are the characters correctly displayed when querying your data? How are you visualizing the resulting CSV? If you're using any program, have you made sure that it's interpreting the file as UTF-8? Finally, if you're specifying a fieldDelimiter, make sure it's a valid one. The delimiter [can be any ISO-8859-1 single-byte character](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_extract).